# Create release but don't copy the jar file anywhere

Tags: git, maven

I would like to create a release tag on git from maven. However, my artifactory is not ready, so I wouldn't want to deploy the release jar anywhere.

I was looking over the [maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html) but the problem is that this seems to fail if I don't set up a location for deployment, according to [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html):

> If the distributionManagement element is not configured within the pom.xml file then the deployment of the artifact will fail. Maven will report a failure back to the user for the execution of the maven-deploy plugin.

So, is there a way of creating a release tag on git without actually deploying the generated artifact?

Comment: What command did you run?

Comment: `mvn release:prepare`

Comment: Your quotation comes from the release:perform goal. According to the documentation the release:prepare shouldn't need any distributionManagement section.

Comment: Could you post your pom please?